# Google Talk over XMPP

Tags: php, xmpp, google-talk, pidgin

I am trying to establish a XMPP connection to `talk.google.com` on port 5222, however I am getting a `301 MOVED PERMANENTLY` response redirecting me to `hangouts.google.com`.

I know Google abandoned GTalk, and what I could find is really inconclusive of whether the service is actually still up and running (although not maintained), or not.

I almost gave up thinking it is just not there anymore, however last try using external client (Adium...like Pidgin but for Mac) instead of my own library ([XMPP-PHP](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/xmpp-php)), ended up actually connecting to the server and sending messages all fine.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the right URL to be `talk.l.google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do an DNS SRV record lookup to find the actual server to connect to, eg https://kingant.net/check_xmpp_dns/?h=gmail.com says that the client records for gmail.com's XMPP server are `xmpp.l.google.com` and `alt{1..4}.xmpp.l.google.com`

Alternatively, you could use a hangups-based solution to speak the native Hangouts protobuf format: https://github.com/tdryer/hangups/

Comment: Unfortunately using any of the addresses just redirects. I don't want to use alternatives because I would like to figure out how to do it myself within my library. Using third-party options may be convenient, but I will gain no knowledge about what I was doing wrong :)